# Is there an HTML "dummy" tag to group other elements without interfering with parent-child CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using Bootstrap, which defines a set of CSS rules. I am trying to use React to render my application, but it always needs a wrapper element, I can't just render an array of elements.

This is not valid:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        );
    }
}
```

But this is:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

In my specific case, I already have a `<ul>` outside, I just need to render a lot of `<li>`s inside. If I use a wrapper tag, it will break Bootstrap rules.

Is there some dummy HTML tag to do this? If not, why?

---

I will explain better my issue. I have this structure (it's a Bootstrap navbar):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <!-- a bunch of <li> generated by AngularJS -->

  <!-- for example, the following my be generated: -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a>Menu 1 Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Menu 1 Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- now, the following is the React component I want to add -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">React Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="my-react-component">
  </li>
</ul>
```

To create it, I am doing:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let x = [];
        for (let lang of langlist) {
            x.push(
              <li>
                ..stuff..
              </li>
            );
        }

        return (
            <something>
                {x}
            </something>
        );
    }
}
```

I also tried to restructure it like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  ...

  <!-- now, the following is the React component I want to add -->
  <li class="dropdown" id="my-react-component"></li>
</ul>
```

And:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let x = [];
        for (let lang of langlist) {
            x.push(
              <li>
                ..stuff..
              </li>
            );
        }

        return (
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">React Menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {x}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

But as you can see I then need another wrapper element, and I can't do it if I want to keep Angular and React.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible now, but [sometime in the future it will be](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127).

Personally, I don't think having a component that renders multiple `<li>` items is smart. A higher level component (the one that renders the `<li>`) should be responsible for the composition of items. All you have to do is combine them into an array and render them in the `<ul>`. The aforementioned thread discusses the dangers of allowing components to return multiple top-level components, though they apparently decided to support it anyway (calling it "fragments") for certain use-cases in a future release.

Comment: I thought about just returning a `<ul>` with `<li>`s inside, but I quickly noticed that the issue was just being "shifted above": the `<ul>` element is not a "only child", it's a sibling of a `<a>` element (because Bootstrap) so I now needed to render `<a>` and `<ul>` together, but that means having another wrapper element... I just want to include a React component in my existing application, I don't (yet) want to port my entire app to React

Comment: It's a little hard for me to follow without seeing more of your code. It sounds like you are trying to make a dropdown? Have you looked at [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), which uses regular bootstrap CSS with React components?

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for the link I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for react limitation, you should return a single DOM element.

I also think you should restructure your components, is not logic a component that isn't a single `li`, I think also that the underlying data is not well-structured

Answer (score 2):

You will always need to have a wrapper for multiple nodes as `render` needs to return a single DOM component. I always use just `<div> ... </div>` and is fine most of the time, unless I need something more specific.

Comment: Yes but if I go `ul > div > li` instead of `ul > li` the CSS rules of Bootstrap will not work

Comment: Yeah, in that case you would have to better structure your components to have a more solid DOM. I think having a component handling both your `ul`s and you `li`s.

Comment: Yes but I only want to use a React component in my existing app, not port the entire app to React... it's just silly that there is no way to work around this issue

Comment: So, what if you handle your `li` from outside that component and just use the component to render it's content? Would that make sense in your app?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, even if it's probably possible to do it with the upcoming version of React, I solved the issue like this:

```
// ugly hack because of react limitation
let x = document.getElementsByTagName("something");
for (let y of x) {
    while (y.childNodes.length > 0) {
        y.parentNode.appendChild(y.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

So I just use `<something></something>` as the "CSS-transparent" element I was hoping existed, and then manually move its children via js